# BeanCurrentlyInCreationException when spring starts

Tags: spring, multithreading

I am getting the BeanCurrentlyInCreationException when I start my spring application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.datayes.bdb.rrp.business.service.impl.StockModelBaseService com.datayes.bdb.rrp.business.service.impl.StockModelV3ServiceImpl.stockModelBaseService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockModelBaseService': Bean with name 'stockModelBaseService' has been injected into other beans [researchFrameworkCommonServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockModelBaseService': Bean with name 'stockModelBaseService' has been injected into other beans [researchFrameworkCommonServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568)
```

And here are the code snippets I have found caused this issue:

```
@Component public class KafkaConsumerServer implements MessageListener<String, String> {
    @Autowired StockModelV3Service stockModelV3Service;
    @Autowired FinanceIndicatorService financeIndicatorService;
    ......
}

@Service public class FinanceIndicatorServiceImpl implements FinanceIndicatorService {
    @Autowired StockModelV3Service stockModelV3Service;
    @Autowired IndustryResearchFrameworkService industryResearchFrameworkService;
    ......
}

@Service public class IndustryResearchFrameworkServiceImpl implements IndustryResearchFrameworkService {
    @Autowired ResearchFrameworkCommonService commonService;
    ......
}

@Service public class ResearchFrameworkCommonServiceImpl implements ResearchFrameworkCommonService {
    @Autowired StockModelBaseService stockModelBaseService;
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some thing interesting in the following article may have explained why. 
https://blog.imaginea.com/spring-bean-creation-is-not-thread-safe/

As both my StockModelV3Service and FinanceIndicatorService depends on stockModelBaseService(FinanceIndicatorService -> industryResearchFrameworkService -> researchFrameworkCommonService -> stockModelBaseService), during spring bean creation, they have raced against each other. Which caused BeanCurrentlyInCreationException. As the above article noted, spring bean creation is not thread safe.

To solve this problem seems easy. I changed autowire order as below:

```
public class KafkaConsumerServer implements MessageListener<String, String> {
    @Autowired FinanceIndicatorService financeIndicatorService;
    @Autowired StockModelV3Service stockModelV3Service;
```

As FinanceIndicatorService also depends on StockModelV3Service, so when financeIndicatorService is loaded, it will wait till stockModelV3Service is loaded then load itself. Thus avoid BeanCurrentlyInCreationException.

After all, it has nothing to do with circular reference. As StockModelBaseService doesn't depends on other services.